# BUG: scheduling while atomic: swapper/0x10010000/0

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm working on kernel code, and I need help with this bug

Here is an example of the prints:

```
BUG: scheduling while atomic: swapper/0x10010000/0
Call Trace:[<80016dbc>][<80016dbc>][<800294e8>][<80186554>][<800294e8>][<80186e70>][<800676fc>][<800b6134>][<800af16c>][<800af108>][<800b6778>][<800b0f94>][<800744d4>][<800510a8>][<80076020>][<800517ec>][<800d4a14>][<800518dc>][<8006c4ec>][<8002da14>][<800d30bc>][<8006c5bc>][<8002da14>][<8006abe4>][<80043ee8>][<8006c4ec>][<8002da14>][<800d30bc>][<800d4a14>][<8006c4ec>][<8006c4ec>][<c00e05a4>][<8004de18>][<80029924>][<c00d7568>][<80029420>][<c005d3e0>][<c00e79f4>][<80028388>][<c00e76e0>][<c00e79f4>][<c005d3e0>][<c005d3e0>][<8002da14>][<c00e4ca0>][<c00e1b8c>][<c00e0e94>][<c00e0ff8>][<80016040>][<8004c0a8>][<800325c8>][<8004de68>][<80032cb4>][<80032cb4>][<800115e0>][<80010ccc>][<80010ce4>][<800115e0>][<80013494>]*
```

```
BUG: scheduling while atomic: downloadManager/0x10010000/715
```

Here is the code added to write to a file:

```
static int writeMsgToFile(const char *data, size_t len) {
    struct file *file;
    mm_segment_t old_fs;
    loff_t pos=0;
    int ret = 0;

    file = filp_open("/var/path/logs", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND , 0666);
    if (IS_ERR(file)) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Failed to open the file: %ld\n", PTR_ERR(file));
        return PTR_ERR(file);       // Return the error code immediately
    }

    old_fs = get_fs();
    set_fs(get_ds());

    ret = file->f_op->write(file, data, strlen(data), &pos);
    if (ret < 0) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Failed to write the data to the file: %d\n", ret);
    } else {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Values written to the file successfully\n");
    }

    set_fs(old_fs);

    filp_close(file, NULL);


    return ret;
}
```

Please let me know if you need the code to debug or please tell me how to proceed on this

Comment: The function calls inside `writeMsgToFile()` can sleep. Perhaps you are calling it from a soft or hard interrupt context, or calling it while a spin-lock is locked? Sleeping in an interrupt context and sleeping while holding a spin-lock are not allowed.